# Error message when trying to review old reputation days

Tags: bug, status-completed

If I go to my (newly designed) user page, on the reputation tab, if I click on one of the days that is not being fully displayed and click on it to get the drop down, I get an error box saying "An error occurred when loading post body." This occurs here in meta.SO, and also in math.SE and other sites. Here's a screen shot from meta.SO:

[image: The error box]

**Edit:** Firebug reveals that a request is made to this address (or similar of course) which returns a `404`:

```
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/userid/username/rep/day/1318982400?sort=post&_=1322066735324
```

Comment: Repro here, extended with further info.

Comment: @Bobby: Thank you, and thanks for editing the image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was fixed in a build last night.  We made a last minute change to put the calls Google shouldn't be crawling under `/ajax/` (for lack of a better term), but the URL the reputation expansion hits to load got missed.

Comment: Thank you for the update and the fix.